# How to customize the color of different messages in one log file

Tags: python, logging, customization, loguru

I am using loguru module in python.
And I want to control that the messages output to a log file have different colors
for instance, if I set the new level is "colorInfo_blue", the default color for "INFO" is white.

```
logger.info("white")
logger.colorInfo_blue("blue")
```

I want these two message have the different color just in one log file.

I have done this:
[image]
But it did not work
[image]

I want to control the color when write the log file.
How shoud I change the code.

Comment: usually log files are normal `plain text` and they can't keep colors. If you would open log file in normal text editor then you would see special codes for terminal/console which changes color only in terminal/console - ie, `\x1b[1;32m` (for bright green color) - and this would be unreadable. And usually programs which write logs they simply removes all colors from text. Eventually you can create own program to display logs and add colors when you display them.